# INSERT statement leaving out one piece

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have a modal pop up that is supposed to upload documents. It does that just fine, except that it doesn't give them a title, therefore nothing shows up on my page since Title is how they show up in the list. What should I replace LinkTitle.Text with to get this to work?
I am trying to fix this guys code because none of it worked right. I added a comment below that has new code in it that is parameterized. This is in ASP.net 4.0 VB using Microsoft SQL Server.

```
    Protected Sub SubmitDocument_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles SubmitDocument.Click
    DocumentModal.Hide()
    'Builds the full absolute URL to be inserted into the database. 
    Dim hostURL As String = Request.Url.Scheme & "://" & Request.Url.Host & ":" & Request.Url.Port & Request.ApplicationPath
    Dim sqlFileHREF As String = "INSERT INTO Marketing (ProductID, MarketingTypeID, MarketingTitle, MarketingData) VALUES (" & ProductID.Value & " ,4, '" & LinkTitle.Text & "', '" & hostURL & "uploads/" & ProductID.Value & "/" & DocumentUpload.FileName & "')"
    sqlFileHREF.Replace("'", "''")
    'Create SQL Connection
    Dim SqlConnection As New SqlConnection("****************************************")
    SqlConnection.Open()
    Dim sqlCommand As New SqlCommand(sqlFileHREF, SqlConnection)
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    SqlConnection.Close()
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
End Sub

       <!-- Add a Document -->
    <li>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="DocumentButton" runat="server">Document</asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:Panel ID="DocumentPanel" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display:none">
            <asp:FileUpload ID="DocumentUpload" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="SubmitDocument" runat="server" Text="Upload" onclick="SubmitDocument_Click" /><asp:Button ID="CancelDocument" runat="server" Text="Cancel" /><asp:HiddenField ID="filename" runat="server" />
        </asp:Panel>       
        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="DocumentModal" runat="server" DropShadow="True" DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" PopupControlID="DocumentPanel" TargetControlID="DocumentButton"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
    </li>
```

Comment: Where are you doing this and with what?

Comment: Side note: Use parameters NOT string concatenation. You're asking for SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: You provide LinkTitle.Text when you show the pop-up, no?

Comment: Some constructive criticism: Don't construct SQL statements like that because they are prone to SQL INJECTION attacks (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Try using Prepared Statements (http://petesbloggerama.blogspot.com/2007/02/sqlite-adonet-prepared-statements.html)

Comment: Actually the pop up is just an upload control. Should I include a text box in there for a user to name their upload? Seems like a silly question, but I didn't write this, just fixing it. After so many problems in one day my brain is kind of fried toward the end.

Comment: I will definitely do some research on parameters and prepared statements. Thanks @Dark Falcon and lcarus

Comment: Your upload control *should* allow you to extract the "title" or any other data from the file information (e.g. filename), or let you override it with user-specified data.

Comment: So how do I mark the answer when it's just comments? gbn you were right, I did not have a LinkTitle in the modal so of course it wasn't inserting anything. (DUH) haha, thank you guys!

Comment: So, if I wouldn't have added the textbox just now, the upload control would've gotten a title? It gets the name of the document with the DocumentUpload.FileName, should I use that twice in the INSERT statement?

Comment: Comment below has reworded code. I have gotten the site to work and have been able to research injection :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code I have now thanks to the people that commented above!

```
<!-- Add a Document -->
    <li>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="DocumentButton" runat="server">Document</asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:Panel ID="DocumentPanel" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display:none">
            Title:<asp:TextBox ID="DocumentTitle" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:FileUpload ID="DocumentUpload" runat="server" />
            <asp:Label ID="DocumentLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Button ID="SubmitDocument" runat="server" Text="Upload" onclick="SubmitDocument_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="CancelDocument" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="filename" runat="server" />
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="DocumentModal" runat="server" DropShadow="True" DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" PopupControlID="DocumentPanel" TargetControlID="DocumentButton"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
      </li>

Protected Sub SubmitDocument_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles SubmitDocument.Click
    DocumentModal.Hide()
    'Builds the full absolute URL to be inserted into the database. 
    Dim hostURL As String = Request.Url.Scheme & "://" & Request.Url.Host & ":" & Request.Url.Port & Request.ApplicationPath

    'SQL INSERT: Marketing Table
    Dim strSQL As String = "INSERT INTO Picklist (Title, Data) VALUES (@Title, @Data);INSERT INTO Marketing (ProductID, MarketingTypeID, MarketingTitle, MarketingData) VALUES (@ProductID,4, 'Document', scope_identity())"
    DocumentUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(String.Format("/uploads/{0}/{1}", ProductID.Value, DocumentUpload.PostedFile.FileName)))

    Using cn As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("LocalSqlServer").ConnectionString)

        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ProductID", ProductID.Value))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Title", DocumentTitle.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Data", hostURL & "uploads/" & ProductID.Value & "/" & DocumentUpload.FileName))

            cn.Open()

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
End Sub
```